# (16 bit asm) Change background and foreground color but stays black and white

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, 16-bit, dosbox

I am using x86 assembly / 16 bit language - using nasm then DOSbox for running the program. I am a second year Bsc CS student and this is my first attempt at doing assembly.

I need to set the video mode, cursor position and color to yellow on blue. I have read documents as well as followed some of the examples given in our module and the color still doesn't change. All it does is clear the window and the color is white on black. I have a feeling that it might be to do with the pixels or something but I am not entirely sure. I would appreciate any advice or hints on how to change my code to work.

```
bits 16 
org 0x100 ; start program at offset 100
;------main program------
main:
;--setting video mode
mov ah,0
mov al,12h
int 10h

;--set cursor position
mov ah,02h
mov dh,10   ;row
mov dl,40   ;column
int 10h

;--changing colour 
mov ah,09h 
mov bl,1eh ;change colour to yellow on blue
int 10h
```

I have messed around with it a few times and would either get a line of constant yellow characters or the display printing over the DOSbox menu or I would just get blue rectangles on the screen. Here is what I get with the code snippet provided:

[Color Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tjvg.jpg)

It seems like I am making a simple mistake but can't quite figure it out - all constructive criticism / help welcome. I would also like to try put the prompts at the left side of the screen and not in the middle if anyone could point me in the right direction for that.

TIA.

Comment: int 10/ah=9 prints the letter in AL, CX times. But you don't set AL to a character to print and the number of characters. http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0099.htm

Comment: Also, when setting the cursor position, you aren't setting bh to the page number (typically 0).

Comment: Also, isn't mode `12h` a graphics mode?  I don't think you can set the background color this way in graphics mode.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have a message printed on the screen which will eventually take input and return more text. I don't know the amount of characters this will produce as yet but if I don't use `mov cx,some value` then it just prints out random characters. How do I get it to stop this and only color what is on the screen and what is to come on the screen at a later time?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Yes, my mistake. I thought because i was changing the background and text that it would be graphical. I changed it to `03h` and it works, but still have all the random characters printed. Would adding an extra carriage return / line feed get rid of this or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for ah=9?  Michael gave you a link above.  In short, you don't put the thing you want to print in cx.  cx is going to contain how many times you want to print it.  The place you put the thing you want to print is al (ie `mov al, 'M'`).

Comment: If you are ok with text mode, you can in DOS also modify the video ram content directly, it resides by default in [memory area starting at `B800:0000`](http://www.shikadi.net/moddingwiki/B800_Text), which is much faster than calling BIOS services (was important back in 80286 days, doesn't make much sense in dosbox on GHz PC), I personally find it also somewhat simpler, as you can do *anything* with the video ram content, you wish.